# what does `uvm_send signify

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

what does `` `uvm_send(seq) `` do?
I am seeing these often in my code.
seq is a uvm_sequence which is being randomized and processed arithmetically.

Where does `` `uvm_send(seq) `` send the sequence?

Comment: https://www.vmmcentral.org/uvm_vmm_ik/files3/macros/uvm_sequence_defines-svh.html#`uvm_send

Comment: "This macro processes the item or sequence that has been created using uvm_create.  The processing is done without randomization.  Essentially, an uvm_do without the create or randomization." -- https://verificationacademy.com/verification-methodology-reference/uvm/docs_1.2/html/files/macros/uvm_sequence_defines-svh.html

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to "A Practical Guide to Adopting the Universal Verification Methodology (UVM) Second Edition", page 202:

*"`uvm_send macro processes the uvm_sequence_item or uvm_sequence class handle argument without any allocation or randomization."*